# Cannot initiate TestNG test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, maven

I'm learning to use selenium WebDriver with TestNG plugging for Eclipse and I ran into this issue where I can't execute the test case (it is unfinished but it has no compile errors nor warnings).

This is my testNG class:

```
package com.selenium.testng.practice;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

public class NewTest {

    public static final String URL = "https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-cl/";
    private WebDriver driver;

    WebElement construccionMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-url='/Construccion_reparacion']"));
    WebElement unfoldedConsMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='navBar-display __activated']"));
    WebElement seguridadInfantil = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='backDisplay __backOn']"
            + "//a[@href='/sodimac-cl/category/cat400014/seguridad-infantil']"));
    WebElement alzadores = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/sodimac-cl/category/cat4850037/Alzadores-y-Sillas-para-autos']"));


    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {        

        System.out.println("Initiating before Method.class..");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        System.out.println("Ending before method...");
    }


    @Test
    public void f() {

        try {

            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(URL);

            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.moveToElement(construccionMenu);
            Assert.assertTrue(unfoldedConsMenu.isDisplayed());
            Assert.assertTrue(seguridadInfantil.isDisplayed());
            seguridadInfantil.click();

            Assert.assertTrue(alzadores.isDisplayed()); 
            alzadores.click();



        } catch (Exception e) {         
            System.out.println("Script failed");
        }


    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        //driver.quit();
    }

}
```

And this is what the console says:

```
> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
> org.testng.TestNGException:  Cannot instantiate class
> com.selenium.testng.practice.NewTest  at
> org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
>   at
> org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(InstanceCreator.java:193)
>   at
> org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:113)
>   at
> org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
>   at
> org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:114)
>   at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:172)   at
> org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:102)     at
> org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:82)
>   at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:74)     at
> org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:39)    at
> org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:463)    at
> org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:342)   at
> org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:295)   at
> org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:226)     at
> org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
>   at
> org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
>   at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:679)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:196)    at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:127)   at
> org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1265)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1244)    at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1093)  at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)   at
> org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77) Caused
> by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   at
> org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:23)
>   ... 26 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
> com.selenium.testng.practice.NewTest.<init>(NewTest.java:21)  ... 31
> more
```

I'm added the libraries using Maven dependencies. Any ideas why I can't execute?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the driver object before actually creating its instance. So when you say driver.FindElement(), the driver instance is null, so the execution is throwing a Null Pointer Exception

You can move the below lines into your f() method to fix the error. So your f() will look like the below.

```
public void f() {

            try {

                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.get(URL);

                WebElement construccionMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-url='/Construccion_reparacion']"));
                WebElement unfoldedConsMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='navBar-display __activated']"));
                WebElement seguridadInfantil = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='backDisplay __backOn']"
                        + "//a[@href='/sodimac-cl/category/cat400014/seguridad-infantil']"));
                WebElement alzadores = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/sodimac-cl/category/cat4850037/Alzadores-y-Sillas-para-autos']"));

                Actions action = new Actions(driver);
                action.moveToElement(construccionMenu);
                Assert.assertTrue(unfoldedConsMenu.isDisplayed());
                Assert.assertTrue(seguridadInfantil.isDisplayed());
                seguridadInfantil.click();

                Assert.assertTrue(alzadores.isDisplayed()); 
                alzadores.click();



            } catch (Exception e) {         
                System.out.println("Script failed");
            }


        }
```

On a best practice, you can start using Page Object Models to separate your identifiers from tests so that this will give you more re usability. You can refer this [link](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/page-object-model-pom-design-pattern-f9588630800b) for PageObjectModel design

Answer (score 0):

You define a class property which tries to initialize with a driver that does not yet exist. So the driver is NULL and you get a NullPointerException. You could move the WebElements to the test method or assign the value after the driver has been set in the beforeMethod

```
construccionMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-url='/Construccion_reparacion']"));
```